# What is the most versatile way to build a custom Wordpress Theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, meta-boxes

I have built WP sites in many different ways over my career, and I am always curious of peoples' methods for building custom WP sites. In the past, I have done everything from hacking together premium themes to do what I want, to building each file in my theme from scratch. Over my evolution as a developer I have currently become mostly satisfied with using a 'starter' blank theme like underscores or understrap. I then use ACF Pro along with custom post types, and that usually covers the majority of what I am trying to accomplish. I have a design background so I design my own stuff sometimes, and I also work with a few very talented designers that push their designs, which I love. This frequently requires highly customized layouts, headers, and footers that I try to couple with an intuitive backend, so the client can change any content on the fly, while having some control over appearances like placement and adding columns.

Second to the Underscores / ACF method, I and surprised how easily I can accomplish the same result with something Like Divi (page builder), where I almost total freedom with code, templates, and custom react modules. Also, the client still gets a drag and drop product that looks very nice on the backend. Sometimes more so than my preferred method. Through both of these methods I always use a child theme so I have very few boundaries when building stuff, but still get to benefit from the theme updates without everything breaking two years down the road.

These are just my own experiences, and since there are many people on this site that have far more experience and know-how than I do. I am interested to here how other people go about always starting with a versatile theme. I am open to trying new types of themes, and also ways to build custom fields, meta-boxes, and taxonomies.

Comment: I think your question falls into different categories of off-topicness (a bit too broad, subject to personal opinions, in a way asking to recommend libraries). But more, i really don't know how i can answer that, even limiting myself to the most versatile _in my opinion/experience_, without writing a long answer saying multiple different things

Comment: haha yeah, I know. I wasn't trying to be selfish by asking this. Meaning I have a system of doing things, and it's fine, but sometimes I hit boundaries that prevent me from doing specially what I want sometimes. I suppose everyone has this happen. I just thought that this is a place where there are more smart people than other places where I have asked something similar. I was just hoping someone would see this and feel like talking about how they do things. So I didn't mean any harm, and wasn't trying to have anyone solve a problem for me. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: My go-to is creating a theme from scratch and revolving around ACF. ACF makes this extremely easy and I have found the majority of page builders including Divi impact site load time and the code isn't put together great (opinion). You can't go wrong building it from scratch, even using a base theme is a no go for me as I prefer to know every single aspect of my theme and not have to find a rock in the road halfway through a project from using someone elses theme.